# How does the digits parameter in R's prettyNum() function work?

Tags: r

In R I'm using the `prettyNum()` function to format some numbers but I'm having a hard time getting the number of digits I want. The help docs say:

> the desired number of digits after the decimal point (format = "f") or significant digits (format = "g", = "e" or = "fg").
>
> Default: 2 for integer, 4 for real numbers. If less than 0, the C default of 6 digits is used. If specified as more than 50, 50 will be used with a warning unless format = "f" where it is limited to typically 324. (Not more than 15–21 digits need be accurate, depending on the OS and compiler used. This limit is just a precaution against segfaults in the underlying C runtime.)

To me, this seems to mean that `prettyNum(404.5142, digits = 2)` should give me `"404.51"` but in reality it produces `"405"`. Can someone explain how to get it to round to a fixed number (say 2) of digits after the decimal place? I'd like it to include tailing 0s too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The help file for `prettyNum` is also documenting `formatC`, to which the parameter `digits` belongs. The `prettyNum` function does not have a parameter called `digits`.

The reason why this doesn't result in an error is that your argument `digits` is being passed via `...` to `format`.

> ...       arguments passed to format.

In `format`, the parameter `digits` is different to the `digits` parameter in `formatC`. It means the number of *significant digits*, not the number of digits after the decimal point. Yes, this is a bit confusing in the documents, but it means for example that you could do:

```r
prettyNum(404.5142, digits = 5)
#> [1] "404.51"
```

However, this will give you the wrong number of digits if you do, for example:

```r
prettyNum(44.5142, digits = 5)
#> [1] "44.514"
```

And therefore you would be safer to use something like `formatC`, which allows

```r
formatC(404.5142, format = "f", digits = 2)
#> [1] "404.51"
```

and

```r
formatC(44.5142, format = "f", digits = 2)
#> 1] "44.51"
```

Which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For anyone else who sees this, the `format = "f"` argument Allan uses is important to prevent scientific notation from cropping up.